# { MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, npm-start

I am very new to node js and mongo db

when i use npm start on my code,
it gives this error

```
server running in production mode on port 5000
{ MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/suyash/Documents/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (/home/suyash/Documents/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/suyash/Documents/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) ok: 0, code: 8000, codeName: 'AtlasError', name: 'MongoError' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@1.0.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node app`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/suyash/.npm/_logs/2020-09-14T23_12_00_524Z-debug.log
```

i was trying to make a app and trying to connect with mongodb database

in db.js file this was my code

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser:true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
        })

        console.log(`MONGODB connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);

        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
module.exports = connectDB
```

i don't know what to do

Comment: Please add more info regarding process.env.MONGO_URI
You should remove the password before adding the URI. I am assuming you are using atlas.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the user role from "Atlas admin" to "Read and write to any database" before it worked on my end.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that I was using the incorrect password, you should use the user password not the account password on your connection string. 
I came across this question while searching for the answer, I'm also pretty new to node and mongo.

[This is where I found the answer](https://wirescript.now.sh/blog/how-to-setup-mongodb-with-node-js-and-express) 
Sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless

Answer (score 0):

I just created a db a user and started but it didnot work.When i added a new user for this db in mongo cloud in worked LOL .